# In energy method for 3D wave equation, why can assume $u_t \nabla u \to 0 $?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In my pde textbook, the proof for conservation of energy for 3d wave goes as following:

$0=(u_{tt}-c^2\Delta u)u_t=(1/2u^2_t+1/2c^2|\nabla u|^2)_t-c^2\nabla\cdot(u_t\nabla u)$

Then integral both sides, and assume $u_t \nabla u \to 0 $, also interchange integral and derivative can get

$0=\int\int\int\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(1/2u_t^2+1/2c^2|\nabla|^2)dx$

I don't understand why can assume $u_t \nabla u \to 0 $ as $|x|\to 0$, where $x$ is in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Comment: are you sure the spatial derivative operators in the first line are correct ($\Delta,\nabla$)?

Comment: @daw sorry, edited

Comment: If you use the divergence theorem, $ \int d^3x \nabla \cdot (u_t \nabla u ) = \oint (u_t \nabla u) \cdot \hat{n} d^2x$ -- where the integral is over the boundary surface of the domain in which you which to solve the wave equation. This would vanish if the gradient of u at the boundary is everywhere perpendicular to the boundary ($\nabla u \cdot \hat{n} = 0 $). Is this true? Alternatively it would vanish if $u$ is constant on the boundary, since $u_t$ would then be zero. Long story short I think for most boundary conditions the term will vanish ?

Comment: @kevinkayaks, thanks! But why $\nabla u \cdot \hat{n} = 0$?

Comment: Just since if that term vanishes then the integrand will always vanish. We have that $u_t ( \nabla u \cdot \hat{n}) = (u_t \nabla u) \cdot \hat{n}$ . 

This said I made an edit. I think it is simply that the term in question vanishes because you are assuming $u$ is constant on the boundary. The "natural" boundary condition in an infinite domain is $u = 0$ on the boundary $x \rightarrow \infty$, hence $u_t = 0$ on that boundary surface also, so the integrand vanishes.

Comment: I believe $u_t = 0$ at the boundary means there is no reflection and no sources of energy there. So I believe the divergence theorem and this fact is the source of ``dropping" the associated term in the energy equation.

Comment: @kevinkayaks Oh, I see, thank you very much!!!